# Get latest entry for each firstName-lastName group with maximum year

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table like below:

```sql
firstName    lastName    updateYear      content       UUID
John           Doe          2010         .......      b2b31m
John           Doe          2010         .......      dksdf2
Jane           Doe          2015         .......      dsfs2k
Jane           Doe          2017         .......      eien1n
Jack           Doe          2019         .......      a2e93h
```

For each firstName-lastName pair, I want the full row with the maximum (latest) year. If there is more than one entry for the same firstName-lastName in the latest year, then I would preferably want the latest row entered (if not possible, any entry would be okay).

So the above table would look like this:

```sql
firstName    lastName    updateYear      content       UUID
John           Doe          2010         .......      dksdf2
Jane           Doe          2017         .......      eien1n
Jack           Doe          2019         .......      a2e93h
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell which database you use. A quite portable and efficient approach is to filter with a row-limiting subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.uuid = (
    select t1.uuid
    from mytable t1
    where t1.firstName = t.firstName and t1.lastName = t.lastName
    order by updateYear desc, uuid desc
    limit 1
)
```

If you have a column that defines the "latest entry", then you can use it instead of `uuid` in the `order by` clause of the subquery.

In SQL Server, you would use `select top (1) ...` instead of `select ... limit 1` in the subquery.

Note that, depending on your database, there are neater options available. For example, if you are running Postgres then `distinct on` comes handy:

```
select distinct on (firstName, lastName) t.*
from mytable t
order by firstName, lastName, updateYear desc, uuid desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `row_number()`. Refer below query for your answer

```
SELECT firstName
    ,lastName
    ,updateYear
    ,content
    ,UUID
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY firstName
            ,lastName ORDER BY updateYear DESC
            ) [row]
    FROM table_name
    ) a
WHERE a.row = 1
```